# Constants for resource suffixes: @2x, ~ipad, -568h

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, retina-display

Are there any Cocoa constants for the various resource suffixes, currently `@2x`, `~ipad` and `-568h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't.

You can see [some documentation here (and in some other places) in Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8) about these strings to name your resources, but there is no Cocoa constants for them.

*Just to be sure, I tried to grep the strings in the SDK directory (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library`)  and those strings were only found in the framework binaries, not in any header file of the SDK.*

Answer (score 0):

MONResourceSuffix.h

```
extern NSString * const MONResourceSuffix_at2x;
extern NSString * const MONResourceSuffix_tilde_ipad;
extern NSString * const MONResourceSuffix_hyphen_568h;
```

MONResourceSuffix.m

```
NSString * const MONResourceSuffix_at2x = @"@2x";
NSString * const MONResourceSuffix_tilde_ipad = @"~ipad";
NSString * const MONResourceSuffix_hyphen_568h = @"-568h";
```

Now there are :)